# why is FFTW input non-zero, output returns all zeros (C++)

Tags: c++, fftw

Ok, so I have been working at the following problem for a while now and can't seem to come to an answer. In short, I am implementing tomographic imaging for a radar signal, and can't seem to get FFTW to give me an output other than zeros. I am implementing via C++ and using the FFTW3 library.

The input for now is a simulated point scatterer at the origin of the scene, which has a phase response of all real ones (see `rxphase` variable).  Because of bandwidth used etc, the IFFT of the filtered received signal should be fairly large (I haven't scaled it  yet) but I am getting zeros for each pulse.

excerpt from my code:

```
void ifftshift(std::vector<phdata> &argin, std::size_t count){
  int k = 0;
  int c = (int)floor((float)count/2);

  if (count % 2 == 0)
  {
    for (k=0; k<c;k++)
    {
      complex<double> tmp = argin[k];
      argin[k] = argin[k+c];
      argin[k+c] = tmp;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    complex<double> tmp = argin[count-1];
    for (k=c-1; k>=0; k--)
    {
      argin[c+k+1] = argin[k];
      argin[k] = argin[c+k];
    }
    argin[c] = tmp;
  }
};

void main(){

  std::vector<complex<double> > filteredData;
  // Number of pulses across the aperture
  std::int pulses = 11;
  // Define the frequency vector
  std::vector<double> freq;
  std::double freqmin = 9 * pow(10,9);
  std::double freqmax = 11 * pow(10,9);
  std::vector<complex<double> > outData;
  std::vector<complex<double> > rxphase;

  for  (int i = 0; i<64; i++)
  {
    freq.push_back(freqmin + (((freqmax-freqmin)/64)*i));
  }

  // Create a (samples X pulses) array of complex doubles
  rxphase.assign(64, std::vector<complex<double> > (11, {1,0}) );

  fftw_complex *in, *out;
  fftw_plan plan;

  in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * image.Nfft );
  out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * image.Nfft );
  plan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(image.Nfft, in, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);

  // iterate through pulses to back project across the aperture
  for ( int i=0; i<=pulses; i++ )
  {
    // Reset vectors for each pulse
    filteredData.clear();
    outData.clear();

    for ( int ii=0; ii<freq.size(); ii++ )
    {
      // Apply simple ramp filter
      filteredData.push_back(freq[ii]*rxphase[ii][i]);
    }

    // Shift the data to put the center frequency at DC position (zero index)
    ifftshift(filteredData, filteredData.size());

    for (int ii=0; ii<filteredData.size(); ii++)
    {
      std::cout << filteredData[ii] ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // filteredData is what I expect it to be.

    // Recast the vector to the type needed for FFTW and compute FFT
    in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&filteredData[0]);

    for (int ii=0; ii<filteredData.size(); ii++)
    {
      std::cout << "(" << (in[ii])[0] << "," << (in[ii])[1] << ");";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // values for in are the same as for filteredData, as expected.

    fftw_execute(plan);

    for (int ii=0; ii<filteredData.size(); ii++)
    {
      std::cout << "(" << (out[ii])[0] << "," << (out[ii])[1] << ");";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    // The values for out are all (0,0)
  }

  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
  //fftw_free(in); error here
  //fftw_free(out); error here
};
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: code should be a little more complete.

Comment: I can't really say what's going wrong here, but I'd recommend using [FFTW++](http://fftwpp.sourceforge.net/) when you're working with FFTW from c++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion probably originates with the line

```
in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&filteredData[0]);
```

While this updates the local variable `in` to points to the area in memory where your data is stored (the storage buffer of the `filteredData` vector), it does not update the pointer kept internally by the `plan`. The area of memory that FFTW knows about and uses as input buffer is thus still the one you had originally allocated with

```
in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * image.Nfft );
```

and specified as argument to

```
fftw_plan_dft_1d(image.Nfft, in, out, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
//                           ^^
```

Note that this memory area remains uninitialized (which *may* happen to be zeros) throughout your program.

You should instead write directly to the `in` input buffer with:

```
for ( int ii=0; ii<freq.size(); ii++ )
{
    // Apply simple ramp filter
    std::complex<double> value = freq[ii]*rxphase[ii][i];
    in[ii][0] = value.real();
    in[ii][1] = value.imag();
}
```

Needless to say that in this case the `in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(&filteredData[0])` line should also be removed.

Alternatively if you are using a compiler where `fftw_complex` and `std::complex<double>` are binary compatible (see [FFTW documentation of Complex numbers type](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-numbers.html)), you may prefer:

```
std::complex<double>* filteredData = reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(in);
for ( int ii=0; ii<freq.size(); ii++ )
{
    // Apply simple ramp filter
    filteredData[ii] = freq[ii]*rxphase[ii][i];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SleuthEye, that solution worked wonderfully. I didn't know about that little quirk with FFTW plans, and so assumed that what I was doing would work (it was a method I had seen used in other posts around here and elsewhere). My program is now happily producing complex image output that I need to get formatted for processing in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick and dirty way of thinking about this, you create `fftw_plan` with  `fftw_plan_dft_1d`  *first*, modify the contents of the effective input array to `fftw_plan_dft_1d` as SleuthEye mentions, and *then* call `fftw_execute`.